# how to get multiple column layout for terminal on mac?

Tags: macos, terminal

I consistently have 3 tabs open in terminal and have to switch between all three tabs all the time. I would like to have all them show tabs split vertically?

like below

[image]

what i want to achieve is to show each tab at the same time. Is that possible?

like below
[image]

Comment: I'd recommend using something like tmux, which is a multiplexer. That will allow three screens in the same terminal. Essentially you can program tmux to run three columns simultaneously

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OS X terminal doesn't have the option to split panes vertically. It is only possible to split horizontally.

I recommend using [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com) on OS X. It has a lot of features missing in default terminal, including possibility to split windows both horizontally and vertically.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is a solution. I think this is another program that is doing 99% of what terminal could do with a few additional scripts.

Comment: but what should be the perfect solution?

Answer (score 16):

As an alternative for multi desktops:

1. Open two terminal windows
2. Toggle one of the terminal windows fullscreen
3. Activate 'Mission Control' (F3 or swipe up with 3 fingers)
4. Drag the second terminal window onto the first's fullscreen space

Comment: This is good but I wish it supported three apps in split screen.